# Automatically declare all missing variables in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ as IDE here is the deal: 
I have multiple classes with dozen of variables not declared .
IntelliJ doesn't seem to have this option when pression Alt+Enter
is there a way  to declare them all in their classes automatically ?

Comment: Why weren't they declared as the code was being written, one at a time?

Comment: it seems that the person used "search and replace all" and I am trying to fix the problem :) LOL

Comment: Then make that person fix it. They learn much faster when they feel the *hurt* of fixing their own mistakes.

Comment: f2, alt-enter, f2, alt-enter... how quick can you do this...

Comment: @vikingsteve hahahahaha Am doing this, but you know how a developer is lazy

Comment: Not lazy... trying to be more efficient ;) On a serious note, you can always use the "open api" and write an intellij plugin to automate / speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a scenario where a class should have a member variable because a method is using it but then it wasn't declared?

I don't think that feature exists in IntelliJ. I believe you can go to a compilation error of undeclared variable, and then ask it to declare it for you... but a bulk fix situation, I don't think that exists.

Comment: Exactly ! so Am I the only one that faced this situation ? :D

Comment: Most likely, yes.  That's a condition that just shouldn't (can't?) happen.  Pull the previous version out of version control and start over.  If you have to go with what you have, go over everything by hand because if you try to automate it you will almost certainly introduce bugs!  You have no idea how many programmers read your post and ran away with their hands to their heads yelling "NO NO NO"

Comment: I think that usually only happens when you have some really major refactoring that went kind of funny. Like, somehow you deleted all your declared vars. I've actually never had a need for this kind of feature, to be honest.

Comment: @BillK I knew it may sound strange but one of my team converted all static methods that he used previously to a variables in the class that why I need find a solution for his new code. Thnx

Comment: So, basically trying to fix too many static methods (static = hard to unit test at times because of mocking challenges)... yeah, I suppose IDEs don't really account for starting for that scenario - usually static methods are done sparingly/where necessary so you wouldn't have a bunch of them to "fix" so-to-speak.